# How can I pop all routes and push a new one popUntil() if it had not been called

Tags: flutter

I am using this code `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'))` to pop all my routes till i get to the particular page registered under the route '/login'. My screen goes blank when the route '/login' is never called and I use `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'))`.

How can I achieve a situation where even if I had not called `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login')` all the routes will be popped and 'login' will be pushed and called.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html) method:

> Push the route with the given name onto the navigator that most
> tightly encloses the given context, and then remove all the previous
> routes until the predicate returns true.

You need to use a [`RoutePredicate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RoutePredicate.html) that always returns false to remove all the previous routes:

```dart
(Route<dynamic> route) => false
```

Here is an example:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  '/login',
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

Comment: is there something for named routes, this seems perfect for anonymous routes. e.g
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(context,'/login',
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);

Comment: I actually saw one for namedRoutes : Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/login', (route) => false);